# How to restore Mac without deleting files

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I must have run an "rm -rf *" command in my root file system (noob mistake I know) as all my files and apps on my mac were deleted, but the computer was still functioning. I've continued working on the mac, and noticed there is no /System/ folder, so I'm thinking maybe I deleted the system folder. Is there a way to restore the file system but keep the apps and files I'm working with?

Comment: You need to get an external harddrive and enable time machine. It's only a matter of time until you loose all your data on your startup drive. I recommend you get a backup before messing with your machine any more.

Comment: btw:  control + c  will quit a terminal command.

Comment: It's not so easy to delete `/System`, have you disabled SIP in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can boot into macOS Recovery by pressing <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> at startup, from there you can reinstall macOS. This *should* leave your files intact, it's nevertheless not a bad idea to do a backkup first.

Apple has described the procedure in detail in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 and https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204904.

Comment: I have done this earlier but if you are really worried about this approach, do backup your files.